# How to Calculate ds Pointer

Tags: disassembly, assembly, malware

How do I calculate the location of the string in this sample located at offset `0x1CAD8`?

The instruction at `0x140001A97` in the sample is:

```
0x140001A97   F2 0F1005 39C60100   movsd xmm0, qword [rip + str..exe]
```

The opcode has `0x39C60100` which is `0x1C639`. If I add that to `rip`, I don't land on the address of the string:

```
0x140001A97 -> offset = 0xE97
```

```
0xE97 + 0x8 + 0x1C639 = 0x1D4D8
```

The string's offset is `0x1CAD8` not `0x1D4D8`

What am I missing?

The sample is Ryuk:
`18faf22d7b96bfdb5fd806d4fe6fd9124b665b571d89cb53975bc3e23dd75ff1`
If you need a copy of the sample, a base64 encoded passworded zip archive with the sample is located here:
https://pastebin.com/aKskMXY7

The password for that zip file is `reseinfected`. If you need something to decode base64 quickly, use this cyberchef recipe:

```
From_Base64('A-Za-z0-9+/=',true)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(14001E0D8-140001A97)-8 = 1C639, VA 14001E0D8 is offset 0001CAD8`

This is the answer. Thanks to an individual on one of the lists I'm on.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing yourself somehow and mixing up file offsets with virtual offsets

lets try a simple example

open a random exe in windbg
patch the bytes in the current instruction Pointer
disassemble
subtract and look

explanation for commands below
cdb is console equivalent for windbg
-c is the command line to be passed to the debugger
eb . is enter bytes at the current instruction pointer (. (dot denotes current ip))
it is followed by bytes from your post

then I disassemble one single instruction at current ip using u . l1
I query what the current ip isby ? $ip
and quit

take the results and do the subtraction with python

```
C:\>cdb -c "eb . F2 0F 10 05 39 C6 01 00;u . l1;? $ip;q" cdb | f:\git\usr\bin\awk "/Reading/,/quit/"
0:000> cdb: Reading initial command 'eb . F2 0F 10 05 39 C6 01 00;u . l1;? $ip;q'
ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x30:
00007ffc`69ad2dbc f20f100539c60100 movsd   xmm0,mmword ptr [xxx (00007ffc`69aef3fd)]
Evaluate expression: 140722081443260 = 00007ffc`69ad2dbc
quit:

C:\>python -c "print (hex(0x7ffc69aef3fd-(0x7ffc69ad2dbc+8)))"
0x1c639
```

rereading your posts it appears you have indeed mixed up raw offsets with virtual offsets
use 0x1a97 instead of 0xe97 (0xc00 bytes accounted for)
locate in which section your string is in
and add the difference between section Va and Section Pointer to RawData
I believe it would account for the remaining 0xa00 bytes